# Memory increasing by 20 MB every time i scale the image

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiimage, uigraphicscontext

I have following method to scale down an image. But Every time i click a picture using my ipad 2 and call this method the Real memory size of the application in instruments goes up up 20 MB. Eventually crashing the application. This method always runs on the main thread. What could be a possible reason for such a huge increase in memory? . I am using ARC.

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image
                  scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
    {
        CGFloat ratioForCompressionAspect = 1.0;
        if ( image.size.width/newSize.width > image.size.height/newSize.height){
            ratioForCompressionAspect = image.size.width/newSize.width;
        }
        else{
            ratioForCompressionAspect = image.size.height/newSize.height;
        }

        newSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width/ratioForCompressionAspect, image.size.height/ratioForCompressionAspect);

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image;
    }
```

EDIT: Some more information : if in this line

```
 [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
```

i Do

```
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
```

The image doesnot scale, but the rize 20mb goes away.

Comment: Using ARC? *This is only here to get past the length limit :)*

Comment: Where is -imageWithImage:scaledToSize: getting called? Is it on the main thread? Can you show us the code where this method is called?

Comment: @DanyJoumaa The question says it 'always runs on the main thread'.

Comment: @Undo Yes I am using ARC.

Comment: Obviously the leak is not here, but you are leaking the image object somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'll hazard a guess here, but i have a theory that you have a reference to the image that you pass into the scale function. You are then overriding image with the scaled image via

```
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

and you then return that. Are you sure you are discarding all references to the original image? otherwise it will sit around in memory, waiting to be used.

Secondly, are you using imageNamed or imageWithData or imageWithContentsOfFile to get your original image? Both imageNamed and imageWithData (depending on how you get the data) can cause the app to cache the file for quicker read speeds later.

I will share a parable i learned from a wise sage of IOS programming after a long and arduous journey "IOS will happily cache stuff for you, however, when it starts to run out of memory, don't expect it to nicely empty that cache for you. It's just as likely to terminate your app and stand there laughing like a maniac. You're far better off avoiding methods that cache data unless the user is going to keep accessing it many times".